# Firebase database query returning TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a request to my Firebase database running the following code:

```
const lastCrawl = admin
  .database()
  .ref('/crawls')
  .orderByChild("dateAdded")
  .limitToLast(1)
  .once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.val();
  });
```

I've written this [based on the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once) and just added some extra steps to deliver only the last record inside the target directory. However, even hardcoding one record from the directory (e.g.: `'/crawls/RECORD-ID'`) would throw the same error, which is strange as the code is basically the same as in the documentation.

Currently it's returning the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection

TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:553:17)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1511:9)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1528:13
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:554:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1511:9)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1528:13
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:554:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1511:9)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1528:13
    at each (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:554:13)
```

Comment: What is your output if you console.log(snapshot.val())?

Comment: You have at least one big difference from the documentation: you're trying to `return` something from the callback, which is not possible since the callback is called asynchronously. See for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40688890/209103, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154617/store-firebase-data-into-array-in-javascript/39155194#39155194 and others from this list: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+asynchronous

Comment: I think you could however write `const last = (await admin
  .database()
  .ref('/crawls')
  .orderByChild("dateAdded")
  .limitToLast(1)
  .once('value'))?.val()`
Can you show your hardcoded document too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank commented, there's a fundamental issue, I was trying to `return` from the callback, which wouldn't work as it's called asynchronously.

The way I decided to solve was to return a promise as done bellow:

```
const getLastCrawl = async () => {
    const ref = admin.database().ref('/crawls/')
    return ref.orderByChild("dateAdded")
      .limitToLast(1)
      .once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => {
        return snapshot.val();
      });
}

const lastCrawl = await getLastCrawl()
```

Thanks a lot for the help Frank!